# C++ STL algorithms: get pointers of elements in container

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl

I have a function that is taking two pointers as parameters.

```
bool function(T* a, T* b);
```

And a container (vector).

```
vector<T> vector;
```

I wish to use an algorithm of the STL (the for_each) to apply the function on the elements of the vector. However, I don't know if the pointers of the elements will go automatically in the function as parameters. For example, will

```
for_each(vector.begin(), vector.end(), function(/*something here?*/))
```

work, or I need to go with a loop (the new for each in loop of the C++11) ?

Comment: I would honestly think the for_each loop is an akward way to do this, but what is it exactly you are trying to do? Are you wanting for each element of the vector[i], to be put through function(vector[i],vector[i+1])

Comment: why not a normal for loop? and access it using [i]

Comment: Wanted to know if there is a way with algorithms, but yes, I don't have a choice and need the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use std::for_each() with your `function` for at least two reasons:

- `std::for_each` passes a single parameter to the lamba, your `function`() takes two parameters.
- `std::for_each` passes a reference to each member of the container, and not a pointer.

Comment: It is possible to write a wrapper function which accepts a reference, obtains pointer to a couple of objects based on that reference, and passes the pointers to `function()`.

Comment: Turning a reference into a pointer is straightforward (I'll let you in on a little secret: it usually takes exactly 0 CPU cycles to do that). However, a reference is a reference to a single object, not a "couple of objects".

Comment: I used the words "based on" for a reason.   There is nothing stopping the wrapper making an assumption that the reference it receives is an element of a `std::vector` (as is the case in this question).  Given the address of one element, it is then possible to reason about the address of other elements.

Comment: Sure, but only if you're careful. If you ass-ume that the other object is the one after what for_each() gives you, and you blindly use for_each() on the entire vector, you might spend a lot of time trying to figure out why your code crashes, every time.

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing a normal for loop for solving this problem.

```
vector<T> v;
for(size_t i(0); i < v.size()-1; ++i)
{
    function(&v[i], &v[i+1]);
}
```

This will pass as the values an address to elements i and i+1 of v which of type T.